# Min SDK 19 require any Support Library?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am developing an app that work from min sdk version 19 onwards. i'm currently using  AppCompatActivity, support v4 fragments and support v7 lib.. 
Is this actually needed for this app?
Can I avoid all support libs..?
Does that increases app performance?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't avoid all support lib.
It will not affect on your application performance. You can definitely avoid adding third party lib in your project till it is necessary to add.

Please read this link. It will give you more detail about Android support libs.

http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/06/android-support-library/